# Group by query in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-transform

I have a Snowflake table like the following one:
[image]

And I wanted to get for each distinct combination "COMPANY"-"BUSINESS UNIT"-"APPROVER LEVEL", the entry with the most recent data (In case we have more than one entry with most recent date it should return all the entries). Thus, considering the table of the example above, it would return the following:
[image]

What is the SQL query I have to write in Snowflake order to obtain this?

Comment: Why does `MAX(Valid_From)` and `GROUP BY col1,col2,col3` not work?

Comment: Because then I do not have an aggregate measure for the approver_name and approver_id

Answer (score 2):

So very similar to Brandon's answer use [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html):

But given you want first ranking items, use [RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rank.html) (which is the same is [DENSE_RANK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dense_rank.html) that Phil mentions)

A CTE for the data (I have used NUMBERS for the valid date, but TEXT would also sort just fine, or converting to DATE also would work the same):

```
WITH sample_data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220406, 'Mr. 0', 'id0' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220406, 'Mr. 1', 'id2' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220212, 'Mr. 2', 'id2' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220130, 'Mr. 3', 'id3' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220320, 'Mr. 4', 'id4' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220115, 'Mr. 5', 'id5' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220102, 'Mr. 6', 'id6' )
    t(company, business_unit, approver_level, valid_from, approver_name, approver_id)
)
```

The following SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM sample_data
QUALIFY rank() over(partition by company, business_unit, approvel_level order by valid_from desc ) = 1;
```

gives:

| COMPANY | BUSINESS_UNIT | APPROVER_LEVEL | VALID_FROM | APPROVER_NAME | APPROVER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | but1 | l1 | 20220406 | Mr. 0 | id0 |
| c1 | but1 | l1 | 20220406 | Mr. 1 | id2 |
| c1 | but1 | l2 | 20220320 | Mr. 4 | id4 |

And if your database is not Snowflake (as you have tagged the issue) and does not have QUALIFY here is the way to do this pattern:

```
WITH smaple_data as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220406, 'Mr. 0', 'id0' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220406, 'Mr. 1', 'id2' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220212, 'Mr. 2', 'id2' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l1', 20220130, 'Mr. 3', 'id3' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220320, 'Mr. 4', 'id4' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220115, 'Mr. 5', 'id5' ),
        ('c1', 'but1', 'l2', 20220102, 'Mr. 6', 'id6' )
    t(company, business_unit, approver_level, 
      valid_from, approver_name, approver_id)
)
SELECT company, business_unit, 
    approver_level, valid_from, 
    approver_name, approver_id
FROM (
    SELECT company, business_unit, 
        approver_level, valid_from, 
        approver_name, approver_id,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY, BUSINESS_UNIT, APPROVER_LEVEL
             ORDER BY  VALID_FROM DESC) as dr
    FROM smaple_data
) 
WHERE dr = 1
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize Qualify to handle this.  To do so, something like this should work

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table_a
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY, BUSINESS_UNIT, APPROVER_LEVEL
                  ORDER BY  VALID_FROM DESC) = 1
;
```

Comment: Ok, in Snwflake the syntax is a little differen, so the query that works is:

SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY, BUSINESS_UNIT, APPROVER_LEVEL
                  ORDER BY  VALID_FROM DESC) 
  FROM table_a
QUALIFY = 1
;

Comment: What about duplicated entries? This solution does not deal with that...
How can I return more than one entry with MAX(VALID_FROM)?

Comment: Can you help me with this @BrandonColeman ?

Comment: @JoãoMiguens Change that row_number to dense_rank

Comment: My syntax will also work in Snowflake, but ya if there are duplicates, something like dense_rank might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is same as suggested by @Brandon Coleman, just need to tweek a bit.

```
with cte as
(
select max(rn) max_rn from (
select rank() over (partition by company,bu,appr_lvl 
order by valid_from) rn 
from your_table_name)
)
select *,rank() over (partition by company,bu,appr_lvl 
order by valid_from) rn 
from your_table_name,cte 
qualify rn>=cte.max_rn;
```